# How can I stop execution of create() method on save button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I am checking a partner name in the table . If it is already exist, then I am showing a warning pop-up using onchange() method as follows :

```
@api.model
@api.onchange('name','is_exist')
def onchange_displayname(self):
    if self.name and self.is_exist is False:
        is_name_exist = self.search([('name', '=', self.name)])
        if is_name_exist:
            self.is_exist = True
            raise ValidationError(_('Alread exist'))
        else:
            pass
```

But when I click on save button, and try to create a duplicate partner. It shows me the Warning pop-up as expected, but in background the partner is getting saved (calling create() method). I don't want to save or create the record until I click on the save button again.

Note : It is working on my local system but not on server . Also ,save button calls onchange() and create() function at a time and not one by one .

Maybe it's a because of system speed . Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried my solution, have I understood well what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two fields, one is `name` and the other is `displayname`, and you don't want to allow names which match with displaynames? If you want to prevent users to create the record, add a constraint to your partners model:

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('displayname', 'name', 'is_exist')
def onchange_displayname(self):
    if self.displayname and self.is_exist is False:
        is_name_exist = self.env['your.partners.model'].search([('name', '=', self.displayname)])
        if is_name_exist:
            raise ValidationError(_('Alread exist'))
        else:
            pass
```

But, if you mean that the only thing you want is avoid two partners who have the same `name`, you'd better implement this functionality with a SQL constraint and using `UNIQUE`. Create it in your partners model:

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('unique_name', 'unique(name)', 'Alread exist'),
]
```

Another way (but not good) to manage what you want is to overwrite the partners ORM `create` method (this means that you should overwrite the ORM `write` method too):

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    partner = super(YourPartnerModel, self).create(vals)
    if partner.displayname and partner.is_exist is False:
        is_name_exist = self.env['your.partner.model'].search([('name', '=', partner.displayname)])
        if is_name_exist:
            self.is_exist = True
            raise ValidationError(_('Alread exist'))
    return partner
```